# Selenium : Does not identify second element from tabbar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using TestNG with java to execute my scripts.
I have a fixed tab bar with 5 elements fixed for all time once the user logged in to the application.

I am able to execute the script by clicking on the first element from the list, but for the second time when I try to click on another element from the tab bar it is failing continuously. I tried adding explicit waits, but is not helping me either.

Here is a snippet of my code:

afterLogin.java

```
public class afterLogin {

WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]")
WebElement button1;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]")
WebElement button2;


 public afterLogin(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver; 
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(300));
    }

    
public void clickButton1() {
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(button1);
     button1.click();
    }

 public void clickButton2(){
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(button2));
        button2.click();
    } 
  }
```

testCase1.java

```
@Test
public void init() throws Exception {
    
      afterLogin obj =  PageFactory.initElements(driver, afterLogin.class);
        
      obj.clickButton1();

}
```

testCase2.java

```
@Test
public void init() throws Exception {
    
      afterLogin obj =  PageFactory.initElements(driver, afterLogin.class);
        
      obj.clickButton2();   /////THIS IS FAILING

}
```

Comment: Could you please debug and check if this condition is failing?
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(button2));`

Comment: No, when I execute testCase2 before testCase1, it is successful. (In this case, testCase1 is failing)

Comment: Could you try updating `xpath` of `button1` and `button2`? Looks like when any of the button is clicked, then xpath is changing. In your case, you are using kind of absolute xpath

Comment: Thanks, I tried updating the relative xpath for both button1 and button2. I am still able to click only one of these buttons

Comment: Could you please debug this code? Add breakpoint for button2. After clicking on button1, please check if the xpath still exists the same for button2

Comment: Yup, the xpath is same even after clicking the button1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241163/discussion-between-user-and-mayank-shukla).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using *Thread.sleep(1000)*. I will try to update my code to use *Implicit waits*, but this solves the purpose for now.

Comment: I would suggest you to use explicit wait. Because using sleep can solve your problem for now. But this is not permanent solution. Sometimes even after using `sleep`, this error can come. That's just a suggestion!!